# Dynamically create a dictionary in python 2.4

Tags: python, python-2.4

I have a query which give me results like this one by one:

```
k1=v1
k2=v2
k3=v3
…
```

The variable to hold the result is tmp. I just wanted to create a dictionary for the results once a result is retrieved.  I tried:

```
result={} 
result.update(tmp)
```

I got

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is
>   required.

I tried this

```
result.update(tmp.replace("=",":"))
```

I got the same err.
I don'twant to do substring to get the keys and values then use d(k1)=v1 to build the dict. is there other good way to do it? I also can change the query and let it generate results like k1:v1, k2:v2,...
How can I dynamically create a dictionary for this in python 2.4?
Thank you!

Comment: What is `tmp`? It should either be a dictionary, or a sequence of `(key, value)` pairs. Your `tmp` input is *neither*, so the error is thrown.

Comment: Incidentally, why are you using 2.4? Not that it affects the answer here.

Comment: Why did you tag this with `python-2.7` if you are really using Python 2.4 instead?

Comment: tmp is string variable, eg. tmp='k1=v1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `tmp` is a string of `k1 = v1` pairs, one per line, you'll need to parse those out into pairs:

```
result = {}
for result in query:
    key, value = result.split('=', 1)
    result[key.strip()] = value.strip()
```

This presumes your query returns individual `'key1=value1'` strings to split out into key and value pairs.

Only use `result.update()` with a *sequence* of key-value pairs, or another dictionary. Just passing in a string won't work; Python treats the string as a sequence of one-character strings, and a one-character string does not fit the requirement for a key-value pair.

Answer (score 1):

You have to split the resulting string into lines, and each line into a pair of strings.  This gives you a valid input for the `dict` constructor:

```
result = dict(line.strip().split("=", 1) for line in tmp.splitlines())
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a query string. If that's the case, then your best friend is `urllib.urldecode()`.

If you actually have a series of newlines, then you'll want to do something a bit more custom.

```
# splitlines will split based on \r or \n or the combination
pairs = tmp.splitlines()
# initialize a dict
output = {}

for pair in pairs:
    # split the k/v into two parts, the 1 means only break off the first =
    k,v = pair.split('=',1)
    # assign to the output dict. (you may want k.strip and v.strip to clear extra
    # unneeded whitespace.
    output[k] = v
```

Or, if you're feeling really fancy and want to do it all:

```
dict(map(lambda x: x.strip(),line.strip().split("=", 1)) for line in tmp.splitlines())
```

Comment: `urldecode()` perhaps? And why not include a sample of how that'd work?

Answer (score 1):

If the results of the query can be stored as a python script into a file `results.py`, another solution is using [execfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile):

```
$ cat results.py
k1="v1"
k2="v2"
$ python
>>> result = {}
>>> execfile("results.py",{},result)
>>> print result
{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}
```